# Series of events while jdk install and then error

Tags: jakarta-ee, sdk, java

I am trying to get JDK (EE) on my system from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html)

I have windows 32 bit and I got the right version `java_ee_sdk-6u4-jdk7-windows.exe`

The series of events which happened are

1. [image]
2. [image]

3.[image]

Why? My understanding is `JRE` is part or `JDK`.

Do I have to get `JRE` separately first?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a copy of the `Java Platform, Standard Edition` (Java SE) for installing this.

Comment: @ swapnil I want to develop EE applications. Why do you want me to get the SE?

Comment: Java EE is built on top of Java SE.